# Segment Controller added in storyboard not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I have added segment control in storyboard and i am not hiding it anywhere. Sometimes `segmentControl` visible and sometimes don't see images.

- [Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mAj2.png).
- [Hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0mzg.png).

Comment: are you using Auto layout ??

Comment: Is it there in hierarchical view while debugging?

Comment: Ya i am using Autolayout, I have even added height Constraint. But still this problem occurs